# Turing Decryption - known-plaintext attack

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm a little stuck. If we know m and m*, then k = remainder(k,p)=remainder(m^(p-2),m*,p). But how can we find k without knowing p?

Comment: what is remainder(x,y,z)?

Answer (score 1):

The Turing encryption consists of a (publicly known) prime $p$ and a secret encryption key $k$. From $k$ and $p$ ist is possible to compute $k^{-1}$ so that the encryption $m^*=\operatorname{remainder}(km,p)$ can be undone per $m=\operatorname{remainder}(k^{-1}m^*,p)=\operatorname{remainder}(k^{-1}km,p)=\operatorname{remainder}(m,p)=m$.
The known-plaintext attack assumes you have $m$, $m^*$ - and also $p$. Only $k$ is unknown. I guess you can take over from here.